# Overlapping cells at bottom left corner

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I need bottom cell to be rounded shaped and overlap with above cell. I tried using corner radius and masked corners but it's not giving result. I have attached design, if anyone can help me out. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can't overlap cells, so you'd have to draw each cell in such a way as to make it _look_ like they overlap.

Comment: Actually you can, using a custom flow layout

Comment: Well, with UITableView, it's like matt said. With UICollectionView, it's easier with a custom flow layout and custom cells.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ColnagoRider/ios-swift-uitableview-with-overlapping-cells-fa2735b59854 this one Helps You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Table view cell and it's `contentView` needs to be not clipping to bounds, and your `imageView` should be clipping to bounds, corner radius, border, etc.

You can create a view instead and do layer staff on it instead and place the image view inside.

Also table view will bring to front cell on select, so you need to disable selection and handle it by your own gesture recognizers, or reorder subviews back each time in `layoutSubviews`, check out my [sample project](https://github.com/PhilipDukhov/OverlappingTableView)